# How do I reload all favicons in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, chromium, google-bookmarks

I use mainly Firefox, but sometimes Chrome, which is why I erase my bookmarks on Chrome sometimes and import them from FF.

How can I reload all bookmarked favicons in Chrome? On Firefox there used to be a tool (that does no longer work). On Chrome I didn't find anything like that at all.

**EDIT:** This is not a duplicate. I found the linked thread before I asked this question, but the dude there has the problem that his favicons won't refresh because of cache related issues. I don't want to refresh them, I just want to initially load them. The tips he got were some commands that clear his cache and make the browser being able to reload a favicon.
This is not the case for me. The problem is that I have a lot of subfolders within my bookmarks and opening every single folder (because "open all bookmarks" isn't recursive) is kind of annying.

Comment: @slhck Reopened and closed as dupe.

Comment: @DavidPostill Please read carefully. This is not a duplicate.

Comment: Your explanation as to why your question isn't duplicate of the proposed duplicate is failing to convince most of those voting to re-open your question. Aside from there being an annoyance, can you explain why the proposed duplicate doesn't accomplish what you need?

Comment: @Twisty: Ok, I added more to the edit. The edit is now bigger than the question itself. :/ Kind of hard to ask for some help on here. But thanks for your tip, I hipe this explanation is ok. :)

Comment: 1) So are your fav icons no loaded in the first place? 2) Do none of the answers to the proposed duplicate help?

Comment: 1. Because I imported them. 2. Yes.